# Lua weak references

Tags: garbage-collection, lua, weak-references

I'm working on a project in Lua where I will be creating tables and storing them in a master table, to be erased at a later time. I will pass around references to these tables to other sibling tables.

```
master = {}
table.insert(master, {name = 'hello'})
table.insert(master, {name = 'world', pre = master[1]})
```

The problem that occurs is that when I wish to erase the reference from the master table, the reference still remains in master[2] here.  Obviously my first solution was to make the tables have weak values. (through .__mode on a metatable, not shown here)

This worked, and would work, so long as I would never store a singly-referenced table within these tables.

```
table.insert(master, {name = 'goodbye', pre = master[2], some_table = {123}})
```

The third element, `some_table` would eventually be collected, because the tables have weak values, and this table (`some_table`) is not referenced anywhere else. This is undesired behavior. My latest solution involves creating "weak reference objects" to the tables within the master table.  A naive implementation follows:

```
function WeakRef(t)
    r = {__mode = 'v', __index = t, __newindex = t}
    setmetatable(r, r)
    return r
end
```

These weak reference objects act similarly to `boost::weak_ptr`s and accomplish my goal, but I am uncertain if they are the best solution to my problem.

Is there a better way; a more elegant solution?
Is my design, which requires this master table, perhaps flawed?

Comment: "The problem that occurs is that when I wish to erase the reference from the master table, the reference still remains in master[2] here." I'm curious as to why this is a problem. Does other code _truly_ need to be notified as to the removal of the object from the master table? Because the GC doesn't guarantee a timeframe for when these things get collected. What exactly is the design intended to do that requires  such tight memory control in Lua?

Comment: They do not necessarily need to be notified right away, per se.  The intended design is a master array indicating physical objects within a simulation, and when the object is no longer necessary, it may be removed.  It is similar to having a set of strong pointers in one array, then spreading around weak pointers to the objects.  My problem is that I am giving objects references to other objects and this can hold up collection if I wish to immediately remove an object from the simulation.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I understand what you're doing. I'm not sure _why_ you're doing it. Since weak references are not guaranteed to immediately disappear, what does it matter if they do or not? That's the part I don't understand: why do the other references need to be weak? Weak references will not prevent accidental use of a dead object, since the GC may not have collected it yet. The only reasons for them to be weak is either to prevent circular dependencies (which Lua doesn't have a problem with) or to manage memory more efficiently. Are you allocating enough data that memory management is an issue?

Comment: I am not allocating enough data that it's an issue at this point. My concerns are less of memory and more of validity. Like if I want to say "this object is dead," then I want it removed and any references to it nil. It is okay to me if this object is hanging around uncollected somewhere until the next sweep; I just do not want any references to it anymore once I declare it "dead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that:

1. You want master to be the "one place" where you define whether an object exists or not
2. Your objects can have links between them

Then probably the simplest architecture is reserving one of the members of each object as a "middle man" in charge of managing the references to others. Here're the steps:

1. Make `master` a regular table (not weak)
2. On each physical object, create a weak table called `links` (or whatever name suits your logic better)
3. Make all `links` tables weak. Use them to store references to other objects.

And this is a possible implementation. I've tried it in Lua 5.1:

```
local function newWeakTable()
  return setmetatable({}, {__mode = "v"})
end

local master = {}

-- create two physical objects
local obj1 = { name = "obj1", links = newWeakTable() }
local obj2 = { name = "obj2", links = newWeakTable() }

-- link them
obj2.links.pre = obj1

-- insert them into master
table.insert(master, obj1)
table.insert(master, obj2)

-- master has 2 objects, and they are linked
assert(#master == 2)
assert(obj2.links.pre == obj1)

-- remove obj1 from master, and remove the variable reference
table.remove(master, 1)
obj1 = nil

-- run gc manually
collectgarbage("collect")

-- master has only 1 object now, and the link has dissapeared
assert(#master == 1)
assert(obj2.links.pre == nil)

print("Everything went as expected")
```

Comment: Wouldn't removing references to a table being removed require iterating over every table within `master`, then recursively searching within those tables' tables, if any?  Making `master` weak sounds interesting though.

Comment: You are supposed to already have a ´master[2]´ variable if you are trying to remove ´master[1]´. After all, they are related.

Comment: They are indeed related, but what am I to do if I have hundreds of objects in `master`? Should I track each reference with another reference, circularly? Normally what I would do if I were programming in C++ is to have a container of strong pointers and distribute weak pointers to those that request them. This is what I am wondering, if it possible to do something like this in Lua, or if there's a Lua-specific way to do this. There doesn't seem to be the concept of a 'strong table.' I was thinking that I could have a `__valid` key set to true, then set it to false when it should be cleaned up.

Comment: I ran out of characters for that last comment, but what I am trying to say is, all of these ideas I can come up with for solving my problem might work in theory, but they increase the work that the scripter has to do in order to make sure all of their references are valid. I'm looking for the best possible solution among these.

Comment: You have to structure your data and code so that if master[2] has a reference to master[1], then master[1] must exist. If master[1] isn't important any more, and you don't have to "tell" master[2], then it shouldn't be in master[2] in the first place.

Comment: A possible solution would be to simply store the id - instead of storing a reference to master[1], simply store 1. And use a function to get master[1] or nil from master[2]

Comment: That is what I was intending to do with the whole idea of weak references. Either that, or some sort of ID/UID system. Do you know of any helpful articles about this particular problem or structuring data and code like what I have here?

Comment: Sorry, as it is right now, I don't. Can you provide more context on your system? I mean, what is really master[1], master[2], etc?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments of the original post, these tables are physical objects in a simulation.

Comment: Hi Chip, I re-read your question, re-thought my answer and completely re-wrote it. I hope this time it helps you better.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and I believe it will be very helpful to me.